# save the data in localstorage with JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I made some test code, but it doesn't work what I want.

I push the data on `localstorage`, and get the data from `localstorag`e. After that, I changed the value of data, and push and add the data on `localsorage`. Then, I checked the data and I was trying to get data with `JSON.parse` function. However, it didn't work.

Here's [a code](https://jsfiddle.net/o72q8jam/6/)

```
var temp1 = {
  'temp1': true,
  'test1': true
};

var temp2 = {
  'temp2': true,
  'test2': true
};

var temp3 = [];
temp3.push(temp1);
localStorage.setItem("testing", JSON.stringify(temp3));

var temp4 = localStorage.getItem("testing");
var temp5 = JSON.parse(temp4);
for(var i=0; i<temp5.length; i++)
{
    temp5[i].temp1 = false;
}
temp3.push(temp5);

localStorage.setItem("testing", JSON.stringify(temp3));
var temp6 = localStorage.getItem("testing"));
var temp7 = JSON.parse(temp6);
for(var j=0; j<temp7.length; i++)
{
    temp7[i].test1 = false;
}
temp3.push(temp7);
localStorage.setItem("testing", JSON.stringify(temp3));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: Please be more explicit. Instead of saying "it doesn't work", clearly state what you wanted to do, what you tried and what happens. If there are any error messages in the console, fix them before posting code here, unless you really don't understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of minor syntax errors as mentioed by si2zle, however the main issue is that when you are pushing `temp5` and `temp7` to `temp3`, you are actually pushing a new array instead of the individual elements.

You need to push each individual element to `temp3` inside the for loop like so

```
for(var i=0; i<temp5.length; i++)
{
    temp5[i].temp1 = false;
    temp3.push(temp5[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the following code:

```
for(var j=0; j<temp7.length; i++)
{
    temp7[i].test1 = false;
}
```

it was j++ not i++ and temp7[j].test1 = false; not temp7[i]

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra ')' at var temp6 = localStorage.getItem("testing"));
    also, while  "temp3.push(temp5);" it pushes array in an array
    like this: [{"temp1":true,"test1":true},[{"temp1":false,"test1":true}]]

```
which creates problem while parsing in the for loop.

for(var j=0; j<temp7.length; i++)
{
    temp7[i].test1 = false;
}
```

Hope this helps:)